# How can i have color axis in bubble chart using Highchart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I  need to develop color axis using bubble highchart with [x, y, z] values , for reference https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#color-by-numbers

I need to develop above mentioned bubble chart which is developed in google chart to High chart [bubble] .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should show us the code of what you have tried so far. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer from this topic - [stepped-color-shading-in-highcharts-doughnut-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142869/stepped-color-shading-in-highcharts-doughnut-chart).

Wrapping bubble's prototype:

```
var bubbleProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.bubble.prototype;

  bubbleProto.axisTypes = ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis'];
  bubbleProto.optionalAxis = 'colorAxis';
  bubbleProto.colorKey = 'y';

  Highcharts.wrap(bubbleProto, 'translate', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    Highcharts.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
  });
```

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/4y3qgdmn/41/

[image: bubble series with color axis]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response but I am facing error as TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined

Comment: Recreate a live example of the problem, e.g. on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Since Highcharts v7.2.0 you can add `coloraxis` module and use it for almost all series types:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,

    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#c6e48b',
        maxColor: '#196127'
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/swL0ngvm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

**Blog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/color-coded-data/