# Using colorAxis in a bubble chart in highcharter / r?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Using the highcharter package, is it possible to use a colorAxis in conjunction with a bubble chart? I usually only see it on matrices, maps, and treemaps, but I would like to use it on a bubble chart or a scatter plot so a reader would not want the colors of the points map to.

Here is a small snippet with what I have:

```
x <- letters
value <- runif(26, min = -5, max = 5)
weight <- runif(26, min = 50, max = 200)
percent <- runif(26, min = 0, max = 1)

data <- data.frame(x,value, weight, percent)

hchart(data, "bubble", hcaes(x = x, y = value, size = weight, color = 
percent), maxSize = "15%")%>%
  hc_colorAxis()
```

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wQjb.png)

So, really, I'm unsure of what I need to do to get the colorAxis to map to the colors on the plot, if it's even possible.

Comment: This is a highchartsjs restriction, by now, you can't use or put a colorAxis in a scatter plot on highcharts

Comment: It is possible in Highcharts with wrapping some methods. See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534527/how-can-i-have-color-axis-in-bubble-chart-using-highchart I am not sure if it can be applied to highcharter package.